# Error: Builder (#2) for pdf output format has an invalid configuration

Tags: errors, texlipse

I have the following problem:
The Builder pdflatex (tex2pdf) does not work. As a result of compilation I got the statement `Error: Builder (#2) for pdf output format has an invalid configuration`. The required Path for the TeX distribution seems to be right: `\usr\bin`. I use the operating system ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit, as
editor eclipse 3.8.1 with the texlipse-plugin and as viewer the newest acroread.
As result I do not get any output.

---

Example edited in from comments

```
\RequirePackage[patch]{kvoptions} 
\documentclass{DissOnlineLatex}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[style=chem-angew,backend=bibtex8,]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\bibliography{Literatur.bib}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\newcommand{\Natural}{{\mathbb{N}}}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{1.0}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{1.0}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{1.0}
\renewcommand{\dbltopfraction}{1.0}
\renewcommand{\dblfloatpagefraction}{1.0}
\include{hyphenations}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{empty}
\include{titlepage}
\maketitle
\include{dedication}
\include{acknowledgement}
\include{abstract}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\addtolength{\headheight}{14.5pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\include{Chapters}
\begin{appendix}\include{appendix}
\end{appendix}
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Tabellenverzeichnis}
\printbibliography
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Literatur}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: Same with pslatex: `Error: Builder (#1) for ps output format has an invalid configuration`; and latex: `Error: Builder (#0) for dvi output format has an invalid configuration`

Comment: That's not quite what I asked but it tells me you have TeX properly set up, which was what I wanted to know :-) By the look of things, you have some files with clashing options. You are going to need to give us a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) of your LaTeX input so that we can help.

Comment: `pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.1.1
Copyright 2013 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.2.49; using libpng 1.2.50
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with poppler version 0.24.5
`

Comment: Please cut this down to a _minimal_ example: as it stands we can't hope to help. For example, `DissOnlineLatex` is non-standard, so we will need to have a link for the source. Please also note you can edit the question to do this!

Comment: http://www.dnb.de/SharedDocs/Downloads/DE/DNB/wir/dissonlineAnleitungLatex.pdf;jsessionid=E59481F1782EF811F84EB598A0593BD9.prod-worker3?__blob=publicationFile

Comment: Those 2 problems are left now: (1)`Option clash for package babel. \usepackage (followed by: [T1]{fontenc})` (...)`Texlipse Build Error` (2)`Undefined control sequence: \ProcessKeyvalOptions{Hyp} (followed by: ) (Occurance: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty)`(...)`Texlipse Build Error`

Comment: (1) The babel option clash is not known in the internet yet?!

Comment: (2) Changed `\usepackage{subfigure}` into `\usepackage{caption,subcaption}`. But it doesn't make it better.

Comment: @Peter: That seems to be a different problem. Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows your problem in a different question. Also please note that TeXLive 2013 is not supported anymore: Install TeXLive 2014.

Comment: For fixing of the 2 problems see here:`http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192831/how-should-i-fix-the-option-clash-for-package-babel-connected-with-undefined`