# How should I fix the "Option clash for package babel" connected with "undefined control sequence" with hyperref?

Tags: hyperref, babel, font-encodings, option-clash

I have these two problems using the German documentclass "DissOnlineLatex" (Manual see:`http://www.dnb.de/SharedDocs/Downloads/DE/DNB/wir/dissonlineAnleitungLatex.pdf;‌​jsessionid=E59481F1782EF811F84EB598A0593BD9.prod-worker3?__blob=publicationFile`):

1. `Option clash for package babel. 
    \usepackage (followed by: [T1]{fontenc})`
    (...)
    `Texlipse Build Error`
2. `Undefined control sequence: \ProcessKeyvalOptions{Hyp}` (followed by: ) `(Occurance: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty)`(...)`Texlipse Build Error`

Result: no pdf-output using pdflatex.

Any ideas how to fix it? (Editor: texlipse 3.8.1, operating system: Ubuntu 14 LTS)

MWE follows:

---

```
\RequirePackage[patch]{kvoptions} 
\documentclass{DissOnlineLatex}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[style=chem-angew,backend=bibtex8,]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\bibliography{Literatur.bib}
\onehalfspacing
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

document class follows (cls-file)

```
% FILE: DissOnlineLatex.cls  Version 2.1
% AUTHOR:
% Universität Duisburg-Essen, Standort Duisburg
% AG Prof. Dr. Günter Törner
% Verena Gondek, Andy Braune, Henning Kerstan
% Fachbereich Mathematik
% Lotharstr. 65., 47057 Duisburg
% entstanden im Rahmen des DFG-Projektes DissOnlineTutor
% in Zusammenarbeit mit der
% Humboldt-Universitaet zu Berlin
% AG Elektronisches Publizieren
% Joanna Rycko
% und der
% DNB - Deutsche Nationalbibliothek

%--- Diese Datei darf nicht verändert werden, alle benötigten
% Anpassungen nehmen Sie in einer der anderen mitgelieferten Dateien vor.---------
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e} 
\ProvidesClass{DissOnlineLatex}[2011/01/05 v2.1 Vorlage zur Erstellung digitaler Hochschulschriften]

% Einstellungen für kvoptions - DOT = DissOnlineTutor
\SetupKeyvalOptions{
    family=DOT,
    prefix=DOT@
}

% Parameter können übergeben werden für die Pakete inputenc, fontenc,
% babel, geometry, report, hyperref
\DeclareStringOption{inputenc}
\DeclareStringOption{fontenc}
\DeclareStringOption{babel}
\DeclareStringOption{geometry}
\DeclareStringOption{report}
\DeclareStringOption{hyperref}

% Übergib die Parameter an die Pakete
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

\PassOptionsToClass{a4paper, 12pt, openright, twoside}{report}
\ifx\DOT@report\@empty
  \LoadClass{report}
\else
  \expandafter\LoadClass\expandafter[\DOT@report]{report}
\fi

\ifx\DOT@inputenc\@empty
  \RequirePackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\else
  \expandafter\RequirePackage\expandafter[\DOT@inputenc]{inputenc}
\fi

\ifx\DOT@fontenc\@empty
  \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\else
  \expandafter\RequirePackage\expandafter[\DOT@fontenc]{fontenc}
\fi

\ifx\DOT@babel\@empty
  \RequirePackage[ngerman]{babel} % Sprachen: Deutsch
\else
  \expandafter\RequirePackage\expandafter[\DOT@babel]{babel}
\fi

% Seitenränder vorgeben
\PassOptionsToPackage{left=3.5cm,top=3cm,right=3.5cm,bottom=4cm}{geometry}
\ifx\DOT@geometry\@empty
  \RequirePackage{geometry} 
\else  
  \expandafter\RequirePackage\expandafter[\DOT@geometry]{geometry}
\fi

% Erzeuge eine Auflistung aller verwendeten Dateien
\listfiles

%-------Absatzformatierung----------------------------------------------------------
\setlength{\parindent}{5mm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3} % 1.3-facher Zeilenabstand 

%-------Neudefinition der Abstract-Umgebung-----------------------------------------
\def\sprachtestE{Abstract}

\if@titlepage
  \renewenvironment{abstract}{%
      \titlepage
      \null\vfil
      \@beginparpenalty\@lowpenalty
      \begin{flushleft}%
        \vspace*{-55\p@}
        \LARGE \bfseries \abstractname
        \@endparpenalty\@M
      \end{flushleft}}%
      {\ifx\abstractname\sprachtestE
      \par\vfil\@Keywords
      \else
      \par\vfil\@Schlagwoerter
      \fi 
      \endtitlepage}
\else
  \renewenvironment{abstract}{%
      \if@twocolumn
        \chapter*{\abstractname}%
      \else
        \small
        \begin{flushleft}%
          {\LARGE\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
        \end{flushleft}%
        \quotation
      \fi}
      {\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}
\fi 

% Makros zum Einlesen der Metadaten (werden in metadata.tex benutzt)
\newcommand*{\Anrede}[1]{\gdef\@Anrede{#1}}
\newcommand*{\Nachname}[1]{\gdef\@Nachname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\NachnameohneUmlaute}[1]{\gdef\@NachnameohneUmlaute{#1}}
\newcommand*{\Vorname}[1]{\gdef\@Vorname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\Geburtsdatum}[1]{\gdef\@Geburtsdatum{#1}}
\newcommand*{\Geburtsort}[1]{\gdef\@Geburtsort{#1}}

\newcommand*{\Typ}[1]{\gdef\@Typ{#1}}
\newcommand*{\Titel}[1]{\gdef\@Titel{#1}}
\newcommand*{\TitelohneUmlaute}[1]{\gdef\@TitelohneUmlaute{#1}}
\newcommand*{\Untertitel}[1]{\gdef\@Untertitel{#1}}

\newcommand*{\GutachterA}[1]{\gdef\@GutachterA{#1}}
\newcommand*{\GutachterB}[1]{\gdef\@GutachterB{#1}}
\newcommand*{\GutachterC}[1]{\gdef\@GutachterC{#1}}

\newcommand*{\Grad}[1]{\gdef\@Grad{#1}}
\newcommand*{\Fach}[1]{\gdef\@Fach{#1}}
\newcommand*{\Fakultaet}[1]{\gdef\@Fakultaet{#1}}
\newcommand*{\Universitaet}[1]{\gdef\@Universitaet{#1}}
\newcommand*{\Dekan}[1]{\gdef\@Dekan{#1}}
\newcommand*{\Rektor}[1]{\gdef\@Rektor{#1}}

\newcommand*{\Abgabedatum}[1]{\gdef\@Abgabedatum{#1}}
\newcommand*{\Pruefungsdatum}[1]{\gdef\@Pruefungsdatum{#1}}

\newcommand*{\Schlagwoerter}[1]{\gdef\@Schlagwoerter{#1}}
\newcommand*{\Keywords}[1]{\gdef\@Keywords{#1}}

% Metadaten einlesen (werden danach benötigt für die Einbindung von hyperref)
\include{metadata}

%--Gewährleistung der Kompatibilität mit hyperref.sty-------------------------------------
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}

\ifpdf
\PassOptionsToPackage{%
    pdftitle={\@TitelohneUmlaute},
    pdfauthor={\@NachnameohneUmlaute},
    pdfsubject={\@Typ},
    pdfkeywords={\@Keywords},
    pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,
        colorlinks=true,                    % bitte nicht ändern!
    linkcolor=black,                    % bitte nicht ändern!
    filecolor=black,                    % bitte nicht ändern!
    urlcolor=black,                     % bitte nicht ändern!
    citecolor=black,                    % bitte nicht ändern!
    pdftex=true,              % bitte nicht ändern!
    plainpages=false,         % bitte nicht ändern!
    hypertexnames=false,      % bitte nicht ändern!
    pdfpagelabels=true,       % bitte nicht ändern!
    hyperindex=true,
        pdfa=true}{hyperref} % bitte nicht ändern! NEU: PDF/A-flag

\ifx\DOT@hyperref\@empty
  \RequirePackage{hyperref}
\else
  \expandafter\RequirePackage\expandafter[\DOT@hyperref]{hyperref}
\fi

\else
   %hier können Sie gegebenenfalls Befehle umdefinieren,
   %die nur für pdfLaTeX vorgesehen sind
    \newcommand{\texorpdfstring}[2]{#2}
\fi


%---GENERIERUNG VON WARNUNGEN / FEHLERMELDUNGEN-------------------------------------------------------
% Zweispaltiger Satz
\if@twocolumn
    \PackageWarning{DissOnlineLatex}{Die Option twocolumn (zweispaltiges Seitenlayout) ist an einigen Hochschulen
          nicht zugelassen. Bitte überprüfen Sie, ob Sie diese Option verwenden dürfen.} 
\fi

% Veraltete oder verbotene Pakete
\AtBeginDocument{
        \@ifpackageloaded{pstricks}
                {\ClassWarning{DissOnlineLatex}
                    {Das Paket pstricks darf nicht verwendet werden. Grafiken dürfen nur als eps- oder pdf-File importiert werden.}}
                {}
        \@ifpackageloaded{bbm}
                {\ClassWarning{DissOnlineLatex}
                    {Das Paket bbm ist nicht zugelassen. Verwenden Sie stattdessen z.B. amsfonts oder amssymb.}}
                {}
        \@ifpackageloaded{curves}
                {\ClassWarning{DissOnlineLatex}
                    {Das Paket curves ist nicht zugelassen. Grafiken dürfen nur als eps- oder pdf-File importiert werden.}}
                {}
        \@ifpackageloaded{epic}
                {\ClassWarning{DissOnlineLatex}
                    {Das Paket epic ist nicht zugelassen. Grafiken dürfen nur als eps- oder pdf-File importiert werden.}}
                {}  
        \@ifpackageloaded{eepic}
                {\ClassWarning{DissOnlineLatex}
                    {Das Paket eepic ist nicht zugelassen. Grafiken dürfen nur als eps- oder pdf-File importiert werden.}}
                {}
        \@ifpackageloaded{epsf}
                {\ClassWarning{DissOnlineLatex}
                    {Das Paket epsf ist nicht zugelassen. Wenn Sie das Paket graphicx verwenden, werden eps-Grafiken direkt unterstützt.}}
                {}
        \@ifpackageloaded{epsfig}
                {\ClassWarning{DissOnlineLatex}{Das Paket epsfig ist nicht zugelassen. Wenn Sie das Paket graphicx verwenden, werden eps-Grafiken direkt unterstützt.}}
                {}
        \@ifpackageloaded{epstopdf}
                {\ClassWarning{DissOnlineLatex}
                    {Das Paket epstopdf ist nicht zugelassen. Wenn Sie das Paket graphicx verwenden, werden eps-Grafiken direkt unterstützt.}}
                {}
        \@ifpackageloaded{xypic}
                {\ClassWarning{DissOnlineLatex}
                    {Das Paket xypic ist nicht zugelassen. Grafiken dürfen nur als eps- oder pdf-File importiert werden.}}
                {}
        \@ifpackageloaded{a4}
                {\ClassWarning{DissOnlineLatex}
                    {Vorsicht, das Paket a4 ist veraltet und die Verwendung kann Fehler verursachen, verwenden Sie stattdessen die report-Option a4paper.}}
                {}
        \@ifpackageloaded{a4wide}
                {\ClassWarning{DissOnlineLatex}
                    {Vorsicht, das Paket a4wide ist veraltet und die Verwendung kann Fehler verursachen, verwenden Sie stattdessen die report-Option a4paper.}}
                {}
        \@ifpackageloaded{doublespace}
                {\ClassWarning{DissOnlineLatex}
                    {Vorsicht, das Paket doublespace ist veraltet und die Verwendung kann Fehler verursachen. Verwenden sie stattdessen das Paket setspace.}}
                {}
        \@ifpackageloaded{euler}
                {\ClassWarning{DissOnlineLatex}
                    {Vorsicht, das Paket euler ist veraltet und die Verwendung kann Fehler verursachen. Verwenden Sie stattdessen das Paket eulervm.}}
                {}
        \@ifpackageloaded{fancyheadings}
                {\ClassWarning{DissOnlineLatex}
                    {Vorsicht, das Paket fancyheadings ist veraltet und die Verwendung kann Fehler verursachen. Verwenden Sie stattdessen das Paket fancyhdr.}}
                {}
        \@ifpackageloaded{isolatin}
                {\ClassWarning{DissOnlineLatex}
                    {Vorsicht, das Paket isolatin ist veraltet und die Verwendung kann Fehler verursachen. Verwenden Sie stattdessen das Paket inputenc, dieses ist bereits als Pflichpaket eingebunden.}}
                {}
        \@ifpackageloaded{isolatin1}
                {\ClassWarning{DissOnlineLatex}
                    {Vorsicht, das Paket isolatin1
                                          ist veraltet und die
                                          Verwendung kann Fehler verursachen. Verwenden Sie stattdessen das Paket inputenc, dieses ist bereits als Pflichpaket eingebunden.}}
                {}
        \@ifpackageloaded{mathpple}
                {\ClassWarning{DissOnlineLatex}
                    {Vorsicht, das Paket mathpple ist veraltet und die Verwendung kann Fehler verursachen. Verwenden Sie stattdessen das Paket mathpazo.}}
                {}
        \@ifpackageloaded{mathptm}
                {\ClassWarning{DissOnlineLatex}
                    {Vorsicht, das Paket mathptm ist veraltet und die Verwendung kann Fehler verursachen. Verwenden Sie stattdessen das Paket mathptmx.}}
                {}
        \@ifpackageloaded{pslatex}
                {\ClassWarning{DissOnlineLatex}
                    {Vorsicht, das Paket pslatex ist veraltet und die Verwendung kann Fehler verursachen. Verwenden Sie stattdessen eines der Pakete mathptmx, helvet mit Option scaled=.95 oder courier.}}
                {}
        \@ifpackageloaded{palatino}
                {\ClassWarning{DissOnlineLatex}
                    {Vorsicht, das Paket palatino ist veraltet und die Verwendung kann Fehler verursachen. Verwenden Sie stattdessen eines der Pakete mathpazo, helvet mit Option scaled=.95 oder courier.}}
                {}
        \@ifpackageloaded{t1enc}
                {\ClassWarning{DissOnlineLatex}
                    {Vorsicht, das Paket t1enc ist veraltet und die Verwendung kann Fehler verursachen. Verwenden Sie stattdessen das Paket fontenc mit Option T1, dies ist bereits über die Pflichtpakete voreingestellt.}}
                {}
        \@ifpackageloaded{times}
                {\ClassWarning{DissOnlineLatex}
                    {Vorsicht, das Paket times ist veraltet und die Verwendung kann Fehler verursachen. Verwenden Sie stattdessen eines der Pakete mathpazo, helvet mit Option scaled=.90 oder courier.}}
                {}
        \@ifpackageloaded{umlaut}
                {\ClassWarning{DissOnlineLatex}
                    {Vorsicht, das Paket umlaut ist veraltet und die Verwendung kann Fehler verursachen. Verwenden Sie stattdessen das Paket inputenc, dieses ist bereits als Pflichpaket eingebunden.}}
                {}
        \@ifpackageloaded{umlaute}
                {\ClassWarning{DissOnlineLatex}
                    {Vorsicht, das Paket umlaute ist veraltet und die Verwendung kann Fehler verursachen. Verwenden Sie stattdessen das Paket inputenc, dieses ist bereits als Pflichpaket eingebunden.}}
                {}
    \@ifpackageloaded{floatflt}
                {\ClassError{DissOnlineLatex}
                    {Das Paket floatflt ist
                                          aufgrund von
                                          Lizenzänderungen verboten.}}
                {}

\@ifpackageloaded{here}
                {\ClassWarning{DissOnlineLatex}
                    {Vorsicht, das Paket here ist veraltet und die Verwendung kann Fehler verursachen. Verwenden Sie stattdessen das Paket float.}}
                {}
    }
```

Comment: Do not load babel, give the the language as a global option.

Comment: I had a short look into the file, please don't use it. Have a look at KOMA-script and do it properly.

Comment: I downloaded `DissOnlineLatex.cls` and tried your example; it shows no error. Update your TeX distribution and retry.

Comment: `http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/koma-script/scrguide.pdf`

Comment: Here's more literature: `http://tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-de/texlive-de.pdf`

Comment: Just leave it out completely, the documentclass loads babel with option ngerman.

Comment: It is not a problem with LaTeX, the template is just bad, even tough the source should provide something better.

Comment: You should try putting `ngerman` as a document class option.

Comment: With the (bad) template comes a doc. You should read that, everything is explained there.

Comment: `\documentclass[ngerman]{DissOnLineLatex]`. I don't know that class, but if it is correctly done, it will propose any option that it doesn't know to every loaded package, babel will recognise it, and there will be no option clash.

Comment: The class loads babel with the options english and ngerman. You don't have to load babel yourself. No matter if it's TL13 or TL14. The error message might be different, tough.

Comment: Without the class file put somewhere, this question is not answerable so either please provide a link or post the class here. Otherwise we will have to close it as *unclear what you are asking*.

Comment: Fixed without a clear description, so I closed it. Nice to read that it works now.

Comment: ...but texlipse doesn't generate anything while not complaining. Neither log-file nor dvi-file nor pdf-file.

Comment: I installed TeXmaker instead of TeXlipse and left out the line `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` in my MWE. Problem (1) is solved. How to fix problem (2)?